# Session is null in web service while using [WebService(EnableSession = true)] attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm trying to get a session variable named "Captcha", that I stored and defined in a controller before. but the "Session" itself throws a null reference exception even while I'm using `[WebService(EnableSession = true)]`.

This is my method: (This is in one of the web services of my ASP.NET MVC project)

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool IsCaptchaCorrect(string captcha)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Captcha"] != null) // "Session" throws a 'NullReferenceException'
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["Captcha"].ToString().ToLower() == captcha.ToLower();
        return false;
    }
```

So, as you can see above, I put the `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] attribute but it still throws an exception.
"Session" itself is working within the controllers, but in web services, I get an exception.
I've read most of the questions about this but none of them worked in my case.

I have no idea what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which web service you are using.. Web API/ASMX or WCF ?

Comment: I'm using ASMX ......................

Comment: did you find anything ?

Comment: @RaviRajindu I'm sorry my friend, this was more than 2 years ago and I can't really recall what I eventually ended up doing. You're gonna have to Google stuff, and maybe also don't use `.asmx` anymore, it's ancient and you can probably achieve everything you do with `.asmx` with ASP.NET Web API.